# Null Pointer Error when sending string via intent

Tags: java, android

I want to send some string to another application, but I've got an Error is Null Pointer when I click buttonSave.

I have set Toast, the result is still an error. Is there another way to get the value in `EditText`?

Code :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(....) {
    View view = ....;

    jadwalShubuh = view.findViewById(R.id.shubuhEditText);
    buttonSave = view.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
            String getShubuh = jadwalShubuh.getText().toString().trim();

            Intent moveString = new Intent("com.package.my.application");
            moveString.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            moveString.putExtra("getShubuh", getShubuh);
            startActivity(moveString);
        }
    });

    actionLoad();
}

private void actionLoad() {
    // Call method findLocation when location != null
    findCityCountryName(location);
}

private void findCityCountryName(Location location) {
    // Another String to setCityName and setCountryName
    callingAPI(cityName, countryName);
}

private void callingAPI(String cityName, String countryName) {
    // Calling API code
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                        if (dateJSON.getString("readable").contentEquals(getMonthReadable)) {
                            String setShubuh = timingsJSON.getString("Fajr");
                            jadwalShubuh.setText(setShubuh);
                        }
    });
}
```

Logcat :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
    at com.package.my.application.pengaturanWaktu.sendData(pengaturanWaktu.java:250)
    at com.package.my.application.pengaturanWaktu.access$000(pengaturanWaktu.java:52)
    at com.package.my.application.pengaturanWaktu$1.onClick(pengaturanWaktu.java:94)
```

Comment: First print log from value - getShubuh and check.

Comment: jadwalShubuh -- this edittext is null have you initialize this variable using findviewbyid??

Comment: I have set Toast below String getShubuh, the result still an error like that

Comment: put your complete code here. That should help in resolving issue. As of now it seems to be you haven't initialized edit text using fineviewbyid.

Comment: @NehaRathore I have initialize by using findviewbyid, if i still write into the code i got an error the code too long from stackoverflow

Comment: put a debug point firstly check jadwalShubuh value , then jadwalShubuh.getText() you will find what's wrong,

Comment: please add xml also

Comment: @NehaRathore I have set by toast String getShubuh, still got an error. Error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: that's why i am saying add Log.d("YOUR",""+ jadwalShubuh); &  Log.d("YOUR 1",""+ jadwalShubuh.getText()) before  String getShubuh = jadwalShubuh.getText().toString().trim(); // because error is here only post that no statement would run

Comment: Please remove .trim() in your string getShubuh  and check this string is not equal to null then set a value.

Comment: @NehaRathore when i set Log.e("TAG", "" + jadwalShubuh.getText()) got not error, when i set String getShubuh = jadwalShubuh.getText().toString() got error :D

Comment: what's the printed value in log can you post here

Comment: most probably jadwalShubuh.getText() -- returned value is null

Comment: @NehaRathore i'm using Log.e("TAG", "" + jadwalShubuh.getText()) and set 121313 in editText then logcat print 121313, but when i set String still got error

Comment: check all occurance of jadwalShubuh

Comment: @NehaRathore I'm so sorry. This is my mistake, i have set wrong findViewById EditText :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your EditText refrence is null , make sure the id in `R.id.shubuhEditText` is correct , and you also have to cast it to EditText as `jadwalShubuh = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.shubuhEditText)`

Comment: This is my mistake, i have set wrong findViewById EditText. Thank you for helping me a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting the Extra the value hasn't been set, as you're making the API call later than the initialization.

A quick fix could be to set the getShubuh String assignation after getting the value from the API :

```
if (dateJSON.getString("readable").contentEquals(getMonthReadable)) {
    String setShubuh = timingsJSON.getString("Fajr");
    jadwalShubuh.setText(setShubuh);
    getShubuh = setShubuh.trim();
}
```

And declare the *getShubuh* String as to be accessible to both methods, as you did with *jadwalShubuh*.

Comment: This is my mistake, i have set wrong findViewById EditText. Thank you for helping me a lot